# Jekyll not Generating Folders

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to use Jekyll to build my portfolio site which is hosted through Github Pages. However, after going through the setup process and watching some tutorials this is what I have in my project folder:
[image]

As you'll notice, it seems to be missing some important folder such as `_layouts`, but it also seems to be working fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials or docs you saw may be missing gem themes, Jekyll 3.2.0 introduced **gem based themes**:  By default you won't have these typical directories:

```
/assets
/_layouts
/_includes
/_sass
```

But you can always overwrite them or copy to your jekyll instance to [modify them](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes).

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!